# Increase Byte Values in NSData

Tags: nsdata, nsmutabledata

I have an NSMutableData holding random ASCII bytes.
I would like to shift the values of those bytes by a value (X).

So let us say I have something like this:

```
02 00 02 4e 00
```

I now want to increase every single byte by 0x01 to get:

```
03 01 03 4f 01
```

What is the best approach for this?

Comment: Iterate through and add one to each byte.  (Is this a trick question?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [mutableBytes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableData/mutableBytes) to get a pointer to your bytes, and treat them like a normal C array.

```
uint8_t originalBytes[] = {0x02, 0x00, 0x02, 0x4e, 0x00};
NSMutableData * myData = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:originalBytes length:5];

uint8_t * bytePtr = [myData mutableBytes];

for(int i = 0; i < [myData length]; i++) {
    bytePtr[i] += 0x01;
}

NSLog(@"%@", myData);
```

There's more info in the Binary Data Programming Guide article, "[Working With Mutable Binary Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/Tasks/WorkingMutableData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002150)".

Also, what you're doing is not "shifting" but merely adding 0x01. "Shifting" typically refers to "[bit shifting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23)".

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
NSString *_chars = @"abcd";
NSMutableData *_data = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:[_chars UTF8String] length:_chars.length];

NSLog(@"Bef. : %@", _data);    
for (int i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) ((char *)[_data mutableBytes])[i]++;
NSLog(@"Aft. : %@", _data);
```

---

the log shows the result:

```
Bef. : <61626364>
Aft. : <62636465>
```